# Is there a known offset limit for NetSuite REST API calls?

Tags: rest, netsuite, erp

world! We are trying to use the [NetSuite SuiteQL REST API](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSTRW/NSTRW.pdf) to pull down data. It works perfectly fine for most of the records we are sourcing, but we hit an interesting snag when we hit large tables.

Since the known limit of a single page of data is 1,000 rows, we are simply calling it with a limit of 1,000 and setting the offsets in 1,000 row increments. Something interesting happens when we get to an offset of 100,000 rows for a record that is larger than 100,000 rows.

If we call https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=98000, we get all the links that we expect.

```
{
"links": [
    {
        "rel": "previous",
        "href": "https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=97000"
    },
    {
        "rel": "first",
        "href": "https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=0"
    },
    {
        "rel": "next",
        "href": "https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=99000"
    },
    {
        "rel": "last",
        "href": "https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=753000"
    },
    {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=98000"
    }
],
"count": 1000,
"hasMore": true,
"items": [
    {
        [heres my data]...
```

Setting it to 99,000, a lot of that information disappears. It's almost as if it thinks this is the last page.

```
{
"links": [
    {
        "rel": "previous",
        "href": "https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=98000"
    },
    {
        "rel": "first",
        "href": "https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=0"
    },
    {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "https://myinstance.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql?limit=1000&offset=99000"
    }
],
"count": 1000,
"hasMore": false,
"items": [
    {
        [heres my data]...
```

Setting it to 100,000 flat out gives me an error.

```
{
"type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5",
"title": "Not Found",
"status": 404,
"o:errorDetails": [
    {
        "detail": "The specified query parameter 'offset' is out of bounds. Provide value between 0 and 753000.",
        "o:errorQueryParam": "offset",
        "o:errorCode": "INVALID_PARAMETER"
    }
]
```

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before? I scoured the documentation and couldn't find any mention of limitation in page offsets, so I'm thinking this might be a bug of some sort (the fact that it even tells you the maximum bounds and it's clearly higher than the offset specified makes me think it's a bug), but hoping someone may have seen this before, and even better, has ideas on how to get around this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the official documentation for NetSuite REST Web Services mentions this limitation [[1](https://nlcorp.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_157909186990.html)]:

> Using SuiteQL queries, you can return a maximum of 100,000 results. For more information, see query.runSuiteQLPaged(options).

Comment: Ooh I must have missed that little bit. That's good to know, but a bit disappointing. Do you know of any workable methods of getting around this that you may have seen before?

Comment: @brian Official documentation on the N/query SuiteScript module [[1](https://nlcorp.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_157960586441.html)]:
> If the SuiteAnalytics Connect feature is enabled in your NetSuite account, there is no limit to the number of results this method can return. If the SuiteAnalytics Connect feature is not enabled, this method can return a maximum of 100,000 results across all pages in the result set.

Comment: Ooh gotcha. We do have that enabled, and oddly enough when we just pass the SuiteQL statement through in a wrapper into a RESTlet, it does return everything. It's just when we use the actual SuiteQL API, it gives us this behavior. I'll chalk this up to a glitch and will open up a support ticket, thanks for the information, this is helpful!

Comment: @brian Did you find out why the API has that limit?

Answer (score 0):

From the Help Center > Executing SuiteQL Queries Through REST Web Services

"Using SuiteQL queries, you can return a maximum of 100,000 results if the SuiteAnalytics Connect feature is disabled. If the feature is enabled, the number of results is unlimited."